# Redirect to login only if user is not authenticated react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-router

I'm trying to implement simple authentication system in react application.. So far I implemented OAuth with Google. And after user successfully log in I get this token from google and then I store it in the cookies. That part works correctly.. So In App.jsx component I have declared routes and created a PriveRoute component. I'm only adding the necessary codes

Routing in App.jsx

```
<Switch>
   <Route path={`${this.props.match.url}/checkout`} component={Checkout} />
   <PrivateRoute path={`${this.props.match.url}/dashboard`} authenticated={Cookies.get('authToken')} component={Dashboard} />
   <Route path={`${this.props.match.url}/profile`} component=
</Switch>
```

PrivateRoute

```
 const PrivateRoute = ({ authenticated, component: Component, ...rest }) => {
            { console.log(authenticated) }
            return <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
                authenticated
                    ? <Component {...props} />
                    : this.props.history.push('/login')
            )} />
        }
```

Both of theese are inside the render method of the App.jsx

I use `js-cookie` to use Cookies.

So after user log in successfully I already set `authToken` as cookie via the express server. So after that express server redirects to `app/dashboard` url. So here in App.jsx as I have routes. The first time after user log in with Google it redirect to dashboard and it works as expected.

But if I refresh the page it always redirects to login page..

I can't figure out what's happening.. Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Is there an option to change the persistence of the sign in? to make sure it persists after the page is refreshed?

Comment: @Ryan - I don't get you.. what do you mean ?

Comment: As in, does the successful authToken cookie maintain after the page has been refreshed? If not, your app will think the user is logged out again. There should be an option to maintain the cookie after the session has been refreshed/closed.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the authToken is maintained after refresh. If the cookie doesn’t persist after refresh and it is just a session token, the client will think the user has logged out.

This may help:

[Keeping user logged in after refresh/using refresh token with Google OAuth2 in React app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272786/keeping-user-logged-in-after-refresh-using-refresh-token-with-google-oauth2-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

Try `Redirect` component instead of pushing

```
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom"
```

You must render a component now

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ authenticated, component: Component, ...rest }) => {
            { console.log(authenticated) }
            return <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
                authenticated
                    ? <Component {...props} />
                    : <Redirect to={{pathname: "/login", state: { from: props.location }}}/>
            )} />
        }
```

Comment: I already tried it.. It gives the same results.. always redirects back to login page after refresh